# Show another day(s) in wpf depends on the day of the week

Tags: c#, wpf, date

I have a WPF application where I want to write this on the top:

"Good (1)Morning/Afternoon/Evening! Today's date: (2)Date/Day of the week. Now you have to concentrate on (3)Wednesday and Thursday."

(1) I would like to write morning if the time between 6 AM between 12 AM, Afternoon if the time between 12:01 AM between 6 PM and Evening if 6:01 PM between 5:59 AM.
(2) I would like to write out the today's date and the day of the week. For example: "Today's date is June 12. 2018., Tuesday.
(3) I would like to write different day of the week after the sentence "you have to concentrate on".
On Monday I would like to write Wednesday, on Tuesday I would like to write Thursday AND Friday etc.

Is there a solution for this?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: There are a bunch of solutions to this (probably, infinitely many). What have you tried? Do you know about the [`DateTime` struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime)?

Comment: You really want to call 5AM evening?

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve the functionality you are lookingf for. You may get better help if you provide some samples of your code.. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace stack_days
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //(1)
            string helloText = "Good " + getHoursText() + " ! ";
            //(2)
            string todayDate = "Today's date is " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " ( " + DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek + " ) ";
            //(3)
            string specialDay = getSpecialDayIfDay();

            string fullText = helloText + todayDate + specialDay;

            Console.WriteLine(fullText);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        private static string getSpecialDayIfDay()
        {
            string info = "You have to concentrate on ";
            if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
            {
                return info + "Wednesday and Thursday";
            }
            else if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
            {
                return info + "Weekend";
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        private static string getHoursText()
        {
            string partOfDay = "";
            int hours = DateTime.Now.Hour;
            if (hours > 18)
            {
                partOfDay = "evening";
            }
            else if (hours > 12)
            {
                partOfDay = "afternoon";
            }
            else if (hours > 6)
            {
                partOfDay = "morning";
            }
            else
            {
                partOfDay = "evening";
            }

            return partOfDay;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it's awesome! :)

Answer (score 2):

> 1. I would like to write morning if the time between 6 AM between 12 AM, Afternoon if the time between 12:01 AM between 6 PM and Evening if 6:01 PM between 5:59 AM.

For determining "morning", "afternoon", "evening" and "night" we need to write our own method. The one I have is slightly different than what you asked for because typically morning starts after midnight (people often say something like "I was up until 2 in the morning!"). However you can see the logic and can change it according to what you prefer.

If we use a 24-hour clock where midnight is `0` (which is what the `Hour` property of a `DateTime` uses), then this makes the calculation pretty easy:

```
public static string GetGeneralTime(DateTime specificTime)
{
    if (specificTime.Hour < 12) return "morning";
    if (specificTime.Hour < 17) return "afternoon";
    if (specificTime.Hour < 21) return "evening";
    return "night";
}
```

---

> 2. I would like to write out the today's date and the day of the week. For example: "Today's date is June 12. 2018., Tuesday.

For this part you can get it automatically from a [`DateTime` string format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) (which includes a "day of the week" format, such as "Monday" (`"dddd"`), or a short form "Mon" (`"ddd"`), and "month name" format like "June" (`"MMMM"`) or a short form "Jun" (`"MMM"`)). Click the link above for more info.

For example this line:

```
Console.WriteLine("Today's date is " + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd. yyyy., dddd"));"
```

Will output: **Today's date is June 12. 2018., Tuesday.**

---

> 3. I would like to write different day of the week after the sentence "you have to concentrate on". On Monday I would like to write Wednesday, on Tuesday I would like to write Thursday AND Friday etc.

To get the concentration days, we should probably create another method since different days have different rules. Here's an example method that returns what you've described above, and for all other days it just returns the next day's DayOfWeek string:

```
public static string GetConcentrationDays(DateTime fromDate)
{
    switch (fromDate.DayOfWeek)
    {
        case DayOfWeek.Monday:
            return "Wednesday";
        case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
            return "Thursday AND Friday";
        default:
            // For any other day, return the next day's day of week
            return fromDate.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek.ToString();
    }
}
```

Now we can put this all together by doing something like:

```
private static void Main()
{            
    // Get the current date and time
    var now = DateTime.Now;

    // Build our greeting string
    var greeting = new StringBuilder();
    greeting.Append("Good " + GetGeneralTime(now) + "! ");
    greeting.AppendLine("Today's date: " + now.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy, dddd. "));
    greeting.AppendLine("Now you have to concentrate on " + GetConcentrationDays(now));

    // Display our greeting to the user
    Console.WriteLine(greeting.ToString());

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image: ![![enter image description here]